# While printing a PDF print its attachments too

Tags: pdf, printing, adobe

Is it possible while printing a PDF which has a word document and few images embedded in it be directly printed along with main [image]document?

Comment: There is no built-in mechanism for doing this in Acrobat; you would need to extract each attachment and print it separately.  That part, you might be able to script the attachment extraction n Acrobat Pro, but I don't believe it can be tied to printing the parent document.